# Turkish Charset Issue * Html

Tags: html, css, character-encoding

Hello stackoverflow community,

There is an issue i could not fix: Turkish characters. They are awkwardly shown bold.

I have tried the solutions I could find:

Meta charset: tried both utf-8 and ISO-8859-9

File Coding: Converted it from ANSI to UTF-8

Google fonts charset: Added latin, latin-ext subsets. Fonts are compatible with Turkish.

I have checked similar issues @stackoverflow but no solution exists except those stated above. Fonts are pulled from a single css file, any font import exists between header tags. There are the codes related to the issue:

```
Meta Tag:
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9"> 

Css imports:
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700&subset=latin,latin-ext);
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,400,300,600,700&subset=latin,latin-ext);
```

[Turkish Characters Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMuq4.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: Problem is about the font Lato, even it is compatible with Turkish lang. Even though the Lato itself includes Turkish charset within latin-ext section, it seems it is problematic when it is imported from Google Fonts.

Here is a screenshot from FontSquirrel

[Turkish characters are shown properly @FontSquirrel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nl4Ja.png)